# Kinect Facial Recognition and Training Images

Tags: kinect

I am using [this](https://github.com/mrosack/Sacknet.KinectFacialRecognition) facial recognition program for the Kinect

The problem is I need it to be able to register and actually keep the images for a training database. Whenever I run it, the program works and is able to detect and recognize the faces but then the images are not kept. What code needs to be changed?

I really need help on this it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;

        // loop through all the Kinects attached to this PC, and start the first that is connected without an error.
        foreach (KinectSensor kinect in KinectSensor.KinectSensors)
        {
            if (kinect.Status == KinectStatus.Connected)
            {
                kinectSensor = kinect;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (kinectSensor == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Kinect found...");
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
            return;
        }

        kinectSensor.SkeletonStream.Enable();
        kinectSensor.ColorStream.Enable(ColorImageFormat.RgbResolution640x480Fps30);
        kinectSensor.DepthStream.Enable(DepthImageFormat.Resolution640x480Fps30);
        kinectSensor.Start();

        AllFramesReadyFrameSource frameSource = new AllFramesReadyFrameSource(kinectSensor);
        this.engine = new KinectFacialRecognitionEngine(kinectSensor, frameSource);
        this.engine.RecognitionComplete += this.Engine_RecognitionComplete;

        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.TrainedFaces.ItemsSource = this.targetFaces;
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32")]
    private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads a bitmap into a bitmap source
    /// </summary>
    private static BitmapSource LoadBitmap(Bitmap source)
    {
        IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
        BitmapSource bs = null;
        try
        {
            bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
               IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
               System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(ip);
        }

        return bs;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles recognition complete events
    /// </summary>
    private void Engine_RecognitionComplete(object sender, RecognitionResult e)
    {
        RecognitionResult.Face face = null;

        if (e.Faces != null)
            face = e.Faces.FirstOrDefault();

        if (face != null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(face.Key))
            {
                // Write the key on the image...
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(e.ProcessedBitmap))
                {
                    var rect = face.TrackingResults.FaceRect;
                    g.DrawString(face.Key, new Font("Arial", 20), Brushes.Red, new System.Drawing.Point(rect.Left, rect.Top - 25));
                }
            }

            if (this.takeTrainingImage)
            {
                this.targetFaces.Add(new BitmapSourceTargetFace
                {
                    Image = (Bitmap)face.GrayFace.Clone(),
                    Key = this.NameField.Text
                });

                this.takeTrainingImage = false;
                this.NameField.Text = this.NameField.Text.Replace(this.targetFaces.Count.ToString(), (this.targetFaces.Count + 1).ToString());

                if (this.targetFaces.Count > 1)
                    this.engine.SetTargetFaces(this.targetFaces);
            }
        }

        this.Video.Source = LoadBitmap(e.ProcessedBitmap);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts the training image countdown
    /// </summary>
    private void Train(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TrainButton.IsEnabled = false;
        this.NameField.IsEnabled = false;

        var timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        timer.Tick += (s2, e2) =>
        {
            timer.Stop();
            this.NameField.IsEnabled = true;
            this.TrainButton.IsEnabled = true;
            takeTrainingImage = true;
        };
        timer.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Target face with a BitmapSource accessor for the face
    /// </summary>
    private class BitmapSourceTargetFace : TargetFace
    {
        private BitmapSource bitmapSource;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the BitmapSource version of the face
        /// </summary>
        public BitmapSource BitmapSource
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.bitmapSource == null)
                    this.bitmapSource = MainWindow.LoadBitmap(this.Image);

                return this.bitmapSource;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What code do _you_ have

Comment: Hi Obet, please try to show what you tried so far. The reason you get downvoted is because you did not show that.

Comment: This is very broad... "What code needs to be changed?"  We don't know your code, you have provided no samples, no tries you attempted to fix the problem, where you think the issue might be, etc.  Unless someone is super human coder, they probably won't be able to help much with the details you provided.  Try explaining things more, and give some attempts on your own, and let us know how those go :)

Comment: Yeah sorry guys the reason why I've just posted the link to the whole codes is that I've been really having a hard time dissecting it. Not very good at programming I am just learning as I go working on my project.

Comment: added a sample code hopefully it is correct

Comment: @Obet Where are you trying to keep the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to save the images to a folder, then I would do something like this:

```
        ...

        if (this.takeTrainingImage)
        {
            this.targetFaces.Add(new BitmapSourceTargetFace
            {
                Image = (Bitmap)face.GrayFace.Clone(),
                Key = this.NameField.Text
            });

            //save image
            JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            BitmapFrame outputFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(LoadBitmap(e.ProcessedBitmap));
            encoder.Frames.Add(face.GrayFace);
            encoder.QualityLevel = 96dpi;

            using (FileStream file = File.OpenWrite("C://Users//Your Name//Documents//Face Trainer//Images//face " + targetFaces.Count + ".jpg"))
            {
                encoder.Save(file);
            }

            this.takeTrainingImage = false;
            this.NameField.Text = this.NameField.Text.Replace(this.targetFaces.Count.ToString(), (this.targetFaces.Count + 1).ToString());

            if (this.targetFaces.Count > 1)
                this.engine.SetTargetFaces(this.targetFaces);
        }

        ....
```

Then to load from the files...

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C://Users//Your Name//Documents//Face Trainer//Images//");
Bitmap[] images = new Bitmap[files.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    images[i] = (Bitmap) Image.FromFile(file, true);
}
```

If you are trying to add the images to an actually database, I would follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database).

I would recommend saving the images to a file since you are beginning, and using databases requires much more work. However, when you are more experienced databases are very effective at this sort of thing. Good luck!:)

Comment: Alright so I added in the code except I changed the encoder.QualityLevel = 96dpi; to encoder.QualityLevel = 90; because I was getting an error. Now it says:

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(System.Uri)' has some invalid arguments 

and 

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'System.Uri'

Comment: @Obet Oh ok check edits... Also I recommend using a writeablebitmap instead of a bitmapsource as it is more efficient and optimized because it doesn't create and dispose a frame each second

Comment: Alright that worked but it takes the full image. I'm not sure how to go about changing to writeablebitmap I will probably just mess up the whole program. How can I save the converted grayscale of the face? and How can I make it so that it scans from the trained image database?

Comment: I am getting this error:Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame'

Comment: @Obet change it to `encoder.Frames.Add(new BitmapFrame(System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
    face.GrayFace.GetHbitmap(),
    IntPtr.Zero,
    Int32Rect.Empty,  System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())));`

Comment: Now this: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame'

I see that you like using kinect SDK. Have you done any programs regarding facial recognition from trained image database?

Comment: @Obet I haven't done any work with trained image databases... Remove the `new BitmapFrame(` and the final `)` but keep everything else... My bad didn't realize that `BitmapFrame` is an interface :P

Comment: Hmmm now it's giving me the previous error. Sorry I'm probably not giving you enough information. The program that I provided in the link contains about 11 or so classes

Comment: Yeah you'll probably figure out much more if you can take a look at the program.. Thanks for all the help

Comment: @Obet Ok... I was right the first time, it should be `encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(face.GrayFace.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,  System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())));`

Comment: Alright this seems to work on it: 
     BitmapFrame outputFrame = BitmapFrame.Create(LoadBitmap(face.GrayFace));

Now the problem is it saves the image only after it is detected. I'd like to be able to save the image with the name in the folder. And then have the face recognition search that folder for matches. Is it okay for me to contact you a different way for some more help? Maybe skype or something? I still need lots of your knowledge